# Tracing pthread scheduling

Tags: linux, multithreading, trace

What I want to do is create some kind of graph detailing the execution of (two) threads in Linux. I don't need to see what the threads do, just when they are scheduled and for how long, a time line basically.

I've spend the last few hours searching the internet for a way to trace the scheduling of pthreads. Unfortunately, the two projects I found require either kernel recompilation ([LTTng](http://lttng.org/)) or glibc patching [(NPTL Trace  Tool)](http://nptltracetool.sourceforge.net/), both of which I can not do (large, centrally managed system, on which I have no sudo rights).

Is there any other way to do something like this or will I have to resort to finding a laptop on which I can patch/recompile whatever I want?

Best regards

PS: I would have linked to both projects, but the site doesn't allow me (reputation < 10). The first search result on Google for the project names is the correct one though.

Answer (score 3):

Superuser privileges are not needed to build an instrumented glibc / libpthread.so.  The [`ptt_trace`](http://nptltracetool.sourceforge.net/ptt_trace.html) program that is part of [NPTL Trace Tool](http://nptltracetool.sourceforge.net/) will run your program using the instrumented library.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I took another look at NPTL TT, but it seems the project hasn't been worked on since 2006 and patching new glibc versions doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like Intel's [VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/)?

Comment: This looks very promising, I will keep this in mind for the future when I'm able to afford that software package.

Comment: I just tried the evaluation version and unless I'm overlooking something, there's no way to get a graphical trace of the threads in the Linux version, a shame really. Basically the Linux version is an expensive version of Helgrind (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html).

Comment: That's a pity - I've never tried it, but thought it looked interesting - the graphs are pretty, but if the Linux version can't generated them, then it's not very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a tool called [pthreadw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreadw/) (on sourceforge)

It's a wrapper library which intercepts calls to the usual functions of the pthread library, and reports stats, like typical times spent playing with locks, condition variables, etc...
It is not currently able to export traces, only textual summary reports.